# Cast error passing request.getParameterMap() to a method expecting Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, dictionary, casting, tomcat7, arrays

I started testing Tomcat 7 and found a cast error I hadn't experienced in Tomcat 5.  Both versions of Tomcat are using the same path to Java 6.

Here is the call from a JSP:

```
ImcKaView entityBrowser=new ImcKaView();
entityBrowser.setParam(request.getParameterMap(),true);
```

Here is the method being called:

```
public void setParam(Map<String,Object> m,boolean convertCollection){/* set param code */}
```

Here is the cast error:

*The method `setParam(Map<String,Object>, boolean)` in the type ImcKa is not applicable for the arguments `(Map<String,String[]>, boolean)`*

Shouldn't I be able to pass a `Map<String,String[]>` to a `Map<String,Object>`?

**Update, after answer, for the Tomcat related part:**

I am well satisfied with the answer chosen, since I explicitly mentioned the cast issue of String[] to Object.

For those coming here who are still perplexed about having this issue only occurring when switching Tomcat versions, the definition of `request.getParameterMap()` wasn't typed in the older Tomcat:

Tomcat 5.5:

```
public java.util.Map getParameterMap()
```

Tomcat 7.0:

```
public java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]> getParameterMap()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics in Java is not covariant. Which means `Map<String,String[]>` is not a subtype of `Map<String,Object>`. The relationship of the type arguments (`String[]` is-a `Object`) does not make the generic types (`Map<String,String[]>` and `Map<String,Object>`) related.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not pass `Map<String,String[]>` to a `Map<String,Object>` (The types are not same). Here you need to use wildcard

```
public void setParam(Map<String, ? extends Object> m, boolean convertCollection){
..
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) is a good explanation of `wildcards` and `bounded wildcards`.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example of wildcard usage. I'm a little confused at the difference between "?" and "? extends Object", but I'm sure I can look it up. It was tough to choose an answer, since his spent more time explaining the problem and yours actually moved into solving it. I just chose time submitted for a tie-breaker. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :) Yeah Java generics and wildcards will take sometime to crack. Keep practicing..